# Blazor WebAssembly App with Individual User Accounts and Store user accounts in-app using gives no local user accounts

Tags: c#, visual-studio, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-5

Creating a new `Blazor WebAssembly App` with `Individual User Accounts` and `Store user accounts in-app` using `Visual Studio 2019 16.8.2` and `.NET 5.0` gives no local user accounts.

[image]

Starting the app it says:

> Before authentication will function correctly, you must configure your
> provider details in Program.cs

Program.cs:

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
        {
            // Configure your authentication provider options here.
            // For more information, see https://aka.ms/blazor-standalone-auth
            builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);
        });

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Clicking on Log in redirects to:

https://localhost:44444/authentication/login-failed

With the following message:

> There was an error trying to log you in: 'Invalid response
> Content-Type: text/html, from URL:
> https:login.microsoftonline.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'

`wwwroot` -> `appsettings.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "Local": {
    "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "33333333-3333-3333-33333333333333333"
  }
}
```

https://aka.ms/blazor-standalone-auth leads to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Standalone Blazor WebAssembly apps seems to either require `Azure Active Directory (AAD)`, `Azure Active Directory B2C (AAD B2C)` or another `Identity Provider (IP)`.

Creating another application with `Individual User Accounts` and `Store user accounts in-app` gives `ASP.NET Core Identity` identity users and their own database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not click self hosted so it wants to connect to and existing server.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Found it here as well https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-identity-server?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: @Ogglas Take a look at the commits in this repo I go through the stages to customise ApplicationUser and setup policies and roles. https://github.com/BrianLParker/AuthApp/commits/master

Answer (score 1):

You can remove that from Index.razor, that's a hard coded message from Index.razor page.

[image: See the index.razor page here]